# Count the number of triplets from an array with sums divisible by 'd'?

Tags: c#, performance

I got this question on my test and I did the only logical thing I could think of, which is run 3 nested loops and count each triplet. I obviously wouldn't pass test cases for large arrays...

How can I make this code more efficient?

```
public static int CountTriplets(int d, List<int> a)
{
    int count = 0;
    int n = a.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++)
            {
                if ((a[i] + a[j] + a[k]) % d == 0)
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a way to avoid the O(n^3) complexity because as far as I can tell, we have to calculate **n * (n-1) * (n-2)** values. I hope someone can prove me wrong.

However the code can still be optimized.

You access `a[i]` in the innermost loop, so that is being done **(n-1) * (n-2)** times.
Same for `a[j]` and the addition `a[i] + a[j]` which both happen **(n-2)** times.

Here is a variant without those redundancies:

```
public static int CountTriplets2(int d, List<int> a)
{
    int count = 0;
    int n = a.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var ai = a[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            var aij = ai + a[j];
            for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++)
                if ((aij + a[k]) % d == 0)
                    count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Both methods calculate the modulus value **n * (n-1) * (n-2)** times, which can also be optimized. To know if `(x+y) % d == 0` we can do `(x % d) + (y % d)` and check if that equals either `0` or `d`. The values `x % d` can be calculated just once for every value in the list. Or alternatively, we can subtract `d` if possible and then check only for `0`. This logic can be extended to any number of added values.

This gives us a new variant, which is becoming less readable but I would expect to be faster:

```
public static int CountTriplets3(int d, List<int> b)
{
    int n = b.Count;
    var a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = b[i] % d;

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var ai = a[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            var aij = ai + a[j];
            if (aij >= d)
                aij -= d;
            for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++)
            {
                var aijk = aij + a[k];
                if (aijk == 0 || aijk == d)
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

We can still optimize this further because we are doing an addition in the innermost loop, but we can actually *calculate* which `a[k]` value we would need for a match:

```
public static int CountTriplets4(int d, List<int> b)
{
    int n = b.Count;
    var a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = b[i] % d;

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var ai = a[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            var aij = ai + a[j];
            if (aij >= d)
                aij -= d;
            var neededForK = aij > 0
                ? d - aij
                : 0;
            for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++)
                if (a[k] == neededForK)
                    count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Test results with 2000 integers on my system, in Release mode, and the same `count` result:

- CountTriplets -> 3.82 sec
- CountTriplets2 -> 3.30 sec (14% less time)
- CountTriplets3 -> 1.09 sec (72% less time)
- CountTriplets4 -> 0.93 sec (76% less time)

Comment: That looks interesting, unfortunately I lack the ability to understand such formulaic reasoning. A practical implementation (as a separate answer) would be great. I'll happily add it to my timing figures.

Comment: FWIW I updated my answer. You should hopefully be able to follow the formulaic reasoning.

Answer (score 4):

The question is a cute variation of [the 3 sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM). So lets first go through the classic 2 loop set lookup 3 sum solution.

1. We are given a list to get 3 variables (\$a\$, \$b\$ and \$c\$) and a constant (\$d\$). In the original problem \$d = 0\$.
2. We know \$a + b + c = d\$, so we can rearrange to find \$c\$. \$c = d - a - b\$
3. We then build a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) of the input list. If the language doesn't have a set data type a [hash map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) can be abuse instead. As both have an \$O(1)\$ lookup.
4. We then just do `input_set.contains(d - a - b)` to drop the inner loop.

Here's an example in Python:

```py
# WARNING: the actual code should exclude duplicate indexed values in both the `values_set` lookup and `b`
def is_three_sum(values: list[int], d: int = 0) -> bool:
    values_set = set(values)
    for a in values:
        for b in values:
            if d - a - b in values_set:
                return True
    return False
```

---

The variation used is cute as we now need to use modular arithmetic. I have renamed the OP's `d` to `e` to not conflate with the \$d\$ in my answer.

1. We have the equation \$a + b + c \mod e = d\$. Where \$d = 0\$.
2. We can expand to \$(a \mod e) + (b \mod e) + (c \mod e) \mod e = d \mod e\$.
3. Rearrange \$(c \mod e) = (d \mod e) - (a \mod e) - (b \mod e) \mod e\$.
4. Simplify \$c \mod e = d - a - b \mod e\$.
5. Now all we need to do is precompute `values_set` to be a set of `c % e` when we do the lookup.

```py
# WARNING: the actual code should exclude duplicate indexed values in both the `values_set` lookup and `b`
def is_three_sum(values: list[int], d: int = 0, e: int = 1) -> bool:
    values_set = {v % e for v in values}
    for a in values:
        for b in values:
            if (d - a - b) % e in values_set:
                return True
    return False
```

How to fix the WARNING:

- `b` is simple and is what your code uses.
- `values_set` can be built at the end of the first loop to not have duplicate values.

```py
def is_three_sum(values: list[int], d: int = 0, e: int = 1) -> bool:
    values_set = set()
    for i in range(len(values)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(values)):
            if (d - values[i] - values[j]) % e in values_set:
                return True
        values_set.add(values[i] % e)
    return False
```

NOTE: you can micro-optimise `values_set` to be an array of size \$e\$ for \$O(1)\$ lookup which avoids hashing.

Finally lets figure out how to change from an 'is' question (`bool`) to the count question (`int`).
Let's change `return True` to `count += 1` and see how the code performs with whitebox testing.

- For simplicity \$e = 1\$ so all integers sum to 0.
- With `values = [0, 1, 2]`: (expected output: \$\binom{3}{3} = 1\$)

  - `i = 0`, `values_set = set()`, \$j \in \{1, 2\}\$
    As `values_set` is empty none of the inputs can be in the set.
  - `i = 1`, `values_set = {0}`, \$j \in \{2\}\$

    - `j = 2`. The moduloed sum of `(0, 1, 2)` is 0 which is in `values_set`. `count += 1`

  The output is 1, as expected.
- With `values = [0, 1, 2, 3]`: (expected output: \$\binom{4}{3} = 4\$)

  - `i = 0`, `values_set = set()`, \$j \in \{1, 2, 3\}\$
    As `values_set` is empty none of the inputs can be in the set.
  - `i = 1`, `values_set = {0}`, \$j \in \{2, 3\}\$

    - `j = 2`. The moduloed sum of `(0, 1, 2)` is 0 which is in `values_set`. `count += 1`
    - `j = 3`. The moduloed sum of `(0, 1, 3)` is 0 which is in `values_set`. `count += 1`
  - `i = 2`, `values_set = {0}`, \$j \in \{3\}\$

    - `j = 3`. The moduloed sum of `(0, 2, 3)` is 0 which is in `values_set`. `count += 1`

  The output is 3, which is *not* as expected.

  The problem is we're missing `(1, 2, 3)`. So when `i = 2` and `j = 3` we should have done `count += 2` to account for both `(0, 2, 3)` and `(1, 2, 3)`.

  Lets change `values_set` to `values_count` and change `values_set.add(values[i] % e)` to `values_count[values[i] % e] += 1`
- With `values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`: (expected output: \$\binom{5}{3} = 10\$)

  - `i = 0`, `values_count = [0]`, \$j \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}\$

    - For all values of `j` we do `count += 0`.
  - `i = 1`, `values_count = [1]`, \$j \in \{2, 3, 4\}\$

    - `j = 2`. The moduloed sum of `(0, 1, 2)` is 0 which is `1`. `count += 1`
    - `j = 3`. The moduloed sum of `(0, 1, 3)` is 0 which is `1`. `count += 1`
    - `j = 4`. The moduloed sum of `(0, 1, 4)` is 0 which is `1`. `count += 1`
  - `i = 2`, `values_count = [2]`, \$j \in \{3, 4\}\$

    - `j = 3`. The moduloed sum of `(0-1, 2, 3)` is 0 which is `2`. `count += 2`
    - `j = 4`. The moduloed sum of `(0-1, 2, 4)` is 0 which is `2`. `count += 2`
  - `i = 3`, `values_count = [3]`, \$j \in \{4\}\$

    - `j = 4`. The moduloed sum of `(0-2, 3, 4)` is 0 which is `3`. `count += 3`

  The output is 10, which is expected.

```py
def count_three_sum(values: list[int], d: int = 0, e: int = 1) -> int:
    count = 0
    values_count = [0] * e
    for i in range(len(values)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(values)):
            count += values_count[(d - values[i] - values[j]) % e]
        values_count[values[i] % e] += 1
    return count
```

<sub>NOTE: all code is untested and provided as a reference</sub>

I have graphed the performance of the algorithms. To show how going from an \$O(n^3)\$ algorithm to an \$O(n^2)\$ algorithm greatly improves the performance of the code.

[image]

```py
def test_orig(a: list[int], d: int = 1):
    count = 0
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            for k in range(j + 1, n):
                if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k]) % d == 0:
                    count += 1
    return count


def test_peil(values: list[int], e: int = 1, d: int = 0) -> int:
    count = 0
    values_count = [0] * e
    for i in range(len(values)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(values)):
            count += values_count[(d - values[i] - values[j]) % e]
        values_count[values[i] % e] += 1
    return count


def test_peil__micro(values: list[int], e: int = 1, d: int = 0) -> int:
    count = 0
    values_count = [0] * e
    values_count[values[0] % e] += 1
    for i in range(1, len(values)):
        d_ = d - values[i]
        for j in range(i + 1, len(values)):
            count += values_count[(d_ - values[j]) % e]
        values_count[values[i] % e] += 1
    return count


import functools
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy
import graphtimer

random.seed(42401)


@functools.cache
def args_conv(size: int) -> tuple[list[int], int]:
    arr = list(range(10 * int(size)))
    random.shuffle(arr)
    return arr[:int(size)], random.randrange(1, max(2, int(size) // 10))


def main():
    fig, axs = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()
    axs.set_yscale('log')
    axs.set_xscale('log')
    (
        graphtimer.Plotter(graphtimer.MultiTimer([test_orig, test_peil, test_peil__micro]))
            .repeat(10, 10, numpy.logspace(0, 2, num=50), args_conv=args_conv)
            .min()
    ).plot(axs, x_label='len(nums)')
    fig.show()
    input()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What did you use 'd' for in your code? You mentioned that d is supposed to be a constant value and you said "where d = 0" but then 
> d - a - b
doesn't make sense to me as remainder set wouldn't contain a negative value

Comment: @evirac `a+b+c=d` shows d is the constant we want to sum to. In your question `d=0` -- `(a[i] + a[j] + a[k]) % d == 0`. "doesn't make sense to me as remainder set wouldn't contain a negative value" are you looking at the first equation or the second which has \$d−a−b\mod e\$? Do you know `-3 % 5 = 2`?

Comment: oh yeah. that makes sense.

Comment: Right idea, but I think you need to keep a counter for `values_set`, and add that instead of a fixed `+= 1`. Take `[2, 8, 14, 20, 26, 32]`, `e=6` as an example. Returns `10`, but should return `20`.

Comment: @DillonDavis I've edited to explain why the `values_count` algorithm works.

Answer (score -1):

While the code completes the task correctly, it has a high time complexity, and for larger input lists, it can be quite inefficient. The time complexity of this code is \$O(n^3)\$, where \$n\$ is the number of elements in the input list `a`. This means that as the size of `a` increases, the execution time of the function will grow significantly.

To make the code run faster, we can use a smarter method . One approach is to use a hashmap (dictionary in C#) to store the frequency of remainders when each element in a is divided by `d`.

```
public static int CountTriplets(int d, List<int> a)
{
    int count = 0;
    int n = a.Count;
    Dictionary<int, int> remainderCount = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int remainder = a[i] % d;
        
        if (remainderCount.ContainsKey(remainder))
        {
            remainderCount[remainder]++;
        }
        else
        {
            remainderCount[remainder] = 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int remainder = a[i] % d;
        int neededRemainder = (d - remainder) % d;

        if (remainderCount.ContainsKey(neededRemainder))
        {
            count += remainderCount[neededRemainder];
        }
        if (neededRemainder == remainder)
        {
            count--;
        }
    }
    return count / 3;
}
```

Comment: This has a totally different outcome compared to both the original code + the variants in my answer. For 2000 ints `(0...1999)` and d=`3`, all those methods return `443778444` but your method gives `444222`.

Comment: I don't understand what's the logic behind this code....